# Add more results to Wordpress tag search

Tags: wordpress, tags

I am trying to modify my tag.php inside Wordpress.  Basically, I have my general loop set to the default five posts per page.  When users click on a tag from my tag cloud, I'd like it to display all of the relevant results by title.   Here is what I have in tag.php:

```
<p>Tag: <?php single_tag_title(); ?></p>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts ()) : the_post (); ?>
                    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent   Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>


                    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

This works perfectly, however it only returns the default amount of five.  When I try to add a wp_query using ('posts_per_page' => 1000) before the loop, it returns all of my sites posts, rather than just for the appropriate tag.  How can add more results?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for the reply SilverKenn, I appreciate it.  I was able to sort it out using this instead.

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'tag'=> get_query_var('tag') );
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
  <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of editing a php file whenever you try to customize something via wordpress, you can modify almost everything using functions.php depending on how you code the theme,

Check out post_limits filter http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_limits

or pre_get_posts http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

you can limit the results using the above filters,

e.g. pre_get_posts

```
function cmk_custom_result( $wp_query ) {
    $post_type = $wp_query->query['post_type'];
    if ( $post_type == 'your-post-type' && is_tag() ) {
        $wp_query->set('posts_per_page', '25');
    }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'cmk_custom_result');
```

post_limist

```
function cmk_post_result_limits( $limit, $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_tag() ) {
        return 'LIMIT 0, 25';
    }
    return $limit;
}
add_filter( 'post_limits', 'cmk_post_result_limits', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use get_query_var to get the correct tag, like: `'tag'=> get_query_var('tag')` then use -1 in your posts array for 'posts_per_page' to get an unlimited number of posts for that tag, otherwise change the number to whatever you want to limit the output.

```
                <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'tag'=> get_query_var('tag') );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
                <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent   Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>


                <?php endwhile; ?>
```